# DJANGO use of static files in combination with paths references

Tags: django

I've posted something similar earlier without being able to find a suitable solution. One of the things I am struggling with is the ability to serve static path / file references within DJANGO html templates. Hopefully, by posting another question I will be able to understand how this works. Done quite some research and read through the DJANGO documentation without being able to find something covering my scenario.

Here we go:

Within my model I use a path reference field

```
class Product_images(models.Model):
product = models.ForeignKey(Products, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
path_to_image = models.CharField(max_length=150,null=True, blank=True)
name = models.CharField(max_length=50,unique=False,blank=True)

class Meta:
    verbose_name = 'Product Image'
    verbose_name_plural = 'Product Images' 

def __str__(self):
    return '{} - {} - {}'.format(self.pk, self.product, self.name)
```

The value of this field is set to (example):
static\images\Product\PowerBI\Receivables\Receivables 6.png

The files are physically stored within the app Main/static/....

My setting file contains:

```
    STATIC_URL = '/static/'
    STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/')
    MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'Main/')
    MEDIA_URL = '/Main/'
```

Then I have two templates within the app where I want to serve these images. One page uses a custom context processor in the following way:

```
{{ product_section }}
```

Which returns html including:

```
html_value += u'<img class="d-block w-100" src="{}" width="400px" height="250x" alt="{}">'.format(productimages_obj.path_to_image,productimages_obj.name)
```

This context processor tag is used within a template returned by the products_view view function.

Now, I want to use the same images within another view gallery_view:

```
def gallery_view(request, requestid, *arg, **kwargs):

productimages = Product_images.objects.filter(product=requestid)
if productimages.exists() != True:
    return HttpResponseNotFound('<h1>Page not found</h1>')

context = {
    'productimages': productimages
}

return render(request, "gallery.html", context)
```

When using the following template tag {{ productimages.path_to_image }} I am getting 404 "GET /Gallery/static/images/Product/PowerBI/Finance/Finance%207.png HTTP/1.1" 404 3485.

The template is coded as following:

```
<section id="gallery" class="bg-light">
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        {% for productimages in productimages %}               
            <div class="col-md">
                <img src="{{ productimages.path_to_image }}" onclick="openModal();currentSlide({{ forloop.counter }})" class="hover-shadow">                   
            </div>          
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
</div>
```

Last but not least Urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
path('', views.home_view, name='home'),
path('Home', views.home_view, name='home'),
path('PowerBI', views.products_view, name='power bi'),
path('Services', views.services_view, name='services'),
path('About', views.about_view, name='about'),
path('Contact', views.contact_view, name='contact'),
path('Gallery/<int:requestid>', views.gallery_view, name='gallery'),
```

] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)

What mistake am I making here? Why does the GET include /Gallery/ within the URL? How do I circumvent this?

Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0):

I would set an image field and in the templates I would use its URL property:

models.py:

```
image = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True)
```

.html file:

```
<img src="{{object.image.url}}" alt="" class="img-fluid">
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work for for me as I could not make this work within the custom context processor. This as i am unable to generate html code with template tags.

Comment: I actually recoded my solution and successfully have been able to use the image field within my project.